# Access listbox - Search for more than one field

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, concatenation

I have a listbox on a form that searches for different records. 
I need to modify the after update event macro so that the Where Condition matches 2 fields in the same record. In this case both the work order and the part number.

```
WO  | PN
----|-----
123 | red
123 | green
123 | blue
456 | red
456 | yellow
```

The default access code is:

```
="[workOrder] = " & "'" & [Screen].[ActiveControl] & "'"
```

so right now it matches only the first column (work order).

I want to modify this listbox to search for both [workOrder] and another text field called [partNumber].

I've tried:

```
="[workOrder] = " & "'" & [Screen].[ActiveControl].[Column](0) & "'" AND "[partNumber] = " & "'" & [Screen].[ActiveControl].[Column](1) & "'"
```

but it doesn't work. Found [this](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=290067) but it doesn't work either.

edited to add details:

The main form: see how the work order matches the selection on the left but the part number doesn't.

[image]

The macro in the after update event of the listbox with the default code created by the access wizard. (CercaRecord = FindRecord)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you use the expression you are building, but the `AND` must be part of the string.

```
="[workOrder] = '" & [Screen].[ActiveControl].[Column](0) & "' AND [partNumber] = '" & [Screen].[ActiveControl].[Column](1) & "'"
```

If `workOrder` is a number column, remove the `''` around the first part.

Note how the syntax coloring is showing what is part of the string and what is not.

Comment: Thanks Andre. I've c/p your syntax but it doesn't work either. I've added a couple of pictures to the post hoping it would make things clearer.

Comment: Oh, this is in a macro. `.Column()` might not be available there. I suggest you convert this macro to VBA and we'll see if that works. It should become a `Docmd.FindRecord` command. @Barbara

Comment: Do you know where I can look out for an example and where I would place the code? I know literally nothing about VBA. Btw, I've replaced the default code with just ="[nOrdine] = " & "'" & [Screen].[ActiveControl].[Column](0) & "'" so I guess "column" is available somehow, I just don't know how to make it work. :p